# Using Json Variable In Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have some code that returns some data from a database in the following json format:

```
{
    "dateTime":  "2021-01-27T10:26:19.595198+11:00",
    "sessionId":  "apples",
    "userId":  "exampleUser"
}
```

For an operation I wish to perform I need to take only the "userId" from this response, how would I do this in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-5.1) and the [Member access operator . (dot)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#member-access-operator-):

```
$data = @'
{
    "dateTime":  "2021-01-27T10:26:19.595198+11:00",
    "sessionId":  "apples",
    "userId":  "exampleUser"
}
'@

($data | ConvertFrom-Json).userId
```